# Customization of the color bars in Plotly's parallel_categories diagram

Tags: plotly

Is it possible to customize the bars in the parallel category diagram? Specifically:

- The order of the colour sometimes appears not in order within the same category (see the example figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scwh1.png), where you can clearly see the dark line appear in the middle, next to Coderre, and it looks very out of place). Is there any trick for forcing them to appear in order?
- Also, is it possible to get rid of the borders in the color bars inside the plot? The black borders will make them appear darker if the figure is small.

Here is the MWE:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px


df = px.data.election()
fig = px.parallel_categories(df, color="total", color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Inferno)
fig.show()
```

I am not sure any methods to resolve this question.

- Make the lines appear in order
- Get rid of the black borders of the color bars